# Get id from foreach loop javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

After looping the delete button, I've been trying to get the id so that I can use it with the onclick function but no luck yet.

```
var table = "";
                    res.data.forEach((value, key) => {
                      table += "<tr>";
                      table += "<td>"+value.post_held+"</td>";
                      table += "<td>"+value.established_officer+"</td>";
                      table += "<td>"+value.date_of_commencement+"</td>";
                      table += "<td>"+value.date_of_termination+"</td>";
                      table += "<td><button id=career"+value.id+" class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>";
                      table += "</tr>";


                      var career = document.querySelector("#career"+value.id);
                      career.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                        alert("done")
                      })
                    });
```

Comment: All you've done is put the HTML that would define that element n a string, you haven't done anything to pass that HTML to the browser so it can add those elements to the page. See [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), the newer [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), ...

Comment: Side note: Putting IDs on all of those elements and then adding separate event handlers for each of them is certainly one way to handle this, but you might look into [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) using a single handler on the table instead.

Comment: and also this `id=career"+value.id+"` would not work

Comment: The event handlers for each of them worked, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you forgot to add `table` to DOM.
You just create a string value which contain html code, but you didn't add this html code into the DOM, so you can not find this DOM element by id.
You can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method to add this element which you want to DOM